# The requested resource (/activiti-explorer) is not available

Tags: apache, activiti

I am facing the following problem :

- I have downloaded Activiti bpm which runs under apache .
- I have installed both; Java jre7 & Java jdk1.7.0_06.
- I set the JAVA_HOME to be  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06`.

But when I try to run the activiti bpm by typing the following in windows 7 command line :

```
C:\activiti-5.10\activiti-5.10\setup>ant demo.start
```

the tomcat server will start and the demo will build successfully, but if I try to navigate to the following link `http://localhost:8080/activiti-explorer` I'm getting the following error :-

```
HTTP Status 404 - /activiti-explorer
________________________________________
type Status report
message /activiti-explorer

description The requested resource (/activiti-explorer) is not available.
________________________________________
Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
```

Comment: Please do try to install `JDK 6`, and then see, if the same issue still persists. It happened with me too so I came back to my previous version i.e. `C:\Windows\system32>java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)` and then it started working again.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, i just added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin to my PATH and it worked fine.

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is the proper way but I seem to have resolved this by copying

activiti-5.10/setup/build/webapps/activiti-explorer.war

to

activiti-5.10/apps/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps

HTH